# Simple modal popup is working in all browser except IE8 and IE9

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using this div to open exit popup using jquery. But it's not showing in IE8 and IE9.

Here is div:

```
<div style="display: none; padding: 10px;" id="exit_content">
    <h3>10% Discount on purchase of this item!</h3><br />
</div>
```

These 2 functions are used to open and close popup on mouse move.

```
function modalOpen (dialog) {
    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('fast', function () {
        dialog.container.fadeIn('fast', function () {
            dialog.data.hide().slideDown('fast');
        });
    });
}

function simplemodal_close(dialog) {
    dialog.data.fadeOut('fast', function () {
        dialog.container.hide('fast', function () {
            dialog.overlay.slideUp('fast', function () {
                $.modal.close();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Here is script used for open and close.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
     if(e.pageY <= 5) {
         // Launch MODAL BOX
         $('#exit_content').modal({onOpen: modalOpen, onClose: simplemodal_close});
     } 
 });
```

This popup is displaying in all browser except IE8 and IE9.

Comment: You really don't want to use the `mousemove` event, it fires thousands of times a second and can be a real performance killer. You'll want to use something like `mouseover`.

Comment: ok thanks, But What is the issue of not displaying popup  in IE8 and IE9?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
     if(e.pageY <= 5) {
```

this is probably what's breaking in IE8 and IE9, try debugging and see what IE is passing as a value of `e`

I don't think pageY is going to be there in old `IE`

Comment: Hi i got this error when i debug code in IE8.  jquery.simplemodal.js, line 8 character 3396. s.removeExpression('height')